# A system of two recurrence relations with contradicting solutions??

Tags: recurrence-relations, markov-chains

I have this system of recurrence relations,

\begin{array}{rl} i p_{i,j} & = p_{i-1,j} \\ j p_{i,j} &= i p_{i,j-1} \end{array}

that I want to solve.

If I iterate through the first relation first, I get that

$$ p_{i,j} = \frac 1{i! j!} p_{0,0} $$

and if iterate through the second relation first I get

$$ p_{i,j} = \frac 1{i! j!} i^j p_{0,0} $$

which is contradicting. And neither of these solutions seems to satisfy both relations!!

So what is going awry?

Comment: Well, the second one tells us that $p_{0,j}=0$ and you quickly deduce that $p_{i,j}=0$ $\forall i,j$.

Comment: wow! thanks! this is really embarrassing!! I will delete the question

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate through the first relation first, you get $$p_{i,j} = \frac{1}{i!}p_{0,j}$$ and then one iteration through the second relation gives you $$p_{0,j} = \frac{0}{j}p_{0,j-i} = 0$$
So in fact this iteration order gives you $p_{i,j} = 0$ $\forall j>0$.

If you iterate through the second relation first, you get, as you claimed, $$p_{i,j} =  \frac{1}{i!j!}i^j p_{0,0}$$
which isn't a contradiction, it just tells you that $p_{0,0} = 0$ as well.

One more look at the first relation confirms that $p_{i,j} = 0$ $\forall i,j$ (as lulu pointed out in the comments).

Comment: thanks. what his tricked me is this:
$$ p_{i,j} {=} \frac 1{i!} p_{1,j} {=} \frac 1{i!} \frac 1{j!} p_{1,0} {=} \frac 1{i!j!} p_{0,0} $$
the first and third equalities are using the first recurrence relation, and second equality using the second recurrence relation